# multi table insert fecthing value from another table

Tags: oracle11g, multi-table

I have tables - **FAKE_CUST**, **PRE_CUST**, **NORMAL_CUST**. Based on the constraint present in **FAKE_CUST** table, the value has to be brought to either **PRE_CUST** or **NORMAL_CUST**.

I am using the follwing code:

```
INSERT ALL
         INTO PRE_CUST(CUST_ID, TOTAL_COST_TRANS) (SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID,C FROM (
                    SELECT CUST_ID, SUM(COST_TRANS) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) as C FROM FAKE_CUST) WHERE C>1000)

         INTO NORMAL_CUST(CUST_ID, TOTAL_COST_TRANS) (SELECT DISTINCT CUST_ID,C FROM (
                    SELECT CUST_ID, SUM(COST_TRANS) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) as C FROM FAKE_CUST) WHERE C<1000)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: By the way, you're not using correct syntax for multi-table insert. The `WHEN` clause comes before `insert_into` clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax which you have used for multi-table insert is not correct to start with.

The `WHEN` clause, which evaluates the condition for insert, has to come before `insert_into`clause.

Your query should look like this:

```
INSERT ALL
   WHEN c > 1000 THEN
      INTO pre_cust (cust_id, total_cost_trans)
   WHEN c < 1000 THEN
      INTO normal_cust (cust_id, total_cost_trans)
   SELECT CUST_ID, SUM(COST_TRANS) OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_ID) as C 
   FROM   FAKE_CUST
```

Comment: thanks a lot...i should have checked the restrictions..its working fine now..:)

Comment: Good to know that. If it helped you, you can +1 and accept the answer!

Comment: dont have enough reputation yet..:(